# Using QGIS field calculator expression on Execute SQL

Tags: qgis, shapefile, field-calculator, sql, performance

The following expression copy only minimum value from group/subset to a new column field in QGIS.

```
Case when "FID_Net"=minimum("class", "FID_Net") Then "FID_Net" Else 0 End
```

But this expression on field calculator takes about an hour to analyze 78000 field rows of data. How to use it on 'Execute SQL' or syntax to perform quickly?

Comment: Is this being performed on a shapefile?

Comment: @DPSSpatial Yes

Comment: An hour sounds about right then! However, if you want to 'execute sql quickly', you should consider using a relational database such as PostgreSQL/PostGIS instead of shapefiles and QGIS processing.

Comment: @DPSSpatial 'statistics by catagories' calculates in just 2 seconds.

Comment: Great stuff! Be sure to post that as the answer if that worked.